# Dynamically create new column to write distinct row values for same id

Tags: sql, sas, duplicates, teradata

In Teradata Sql (also could do in SAS, if possible) I'm trying to root out duplicates for a few fields where there are more than one distinct value for a given ID. I don't want to lose the new distinct value in that column so I would like to write it as a new column. There could be any number of distinct values, so it would have to dynamically count each distinct and write a new column for each. Below is the table example:

```
 ID |   V1    |    V2   |
 A  |  Mike   |    25   |
 A  |  Mike   |    26   |
 A  |  Mike   |    27   |
```

To:

```
 ID |   V1    |  V2  | V2.1 | V2.2 |
 A  |  Mike   |  25  |  26  |  27  |
```

Comment: What's the expected result if another Mike row is inserted? Do you want a fourth column to suddenly appear?

Comment: @jarlh yes, I would like to add columns until Mike is a new "ID"

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily in SAS using `proc transpose` which will dynamically create new columns. In this case you set the `by` variable to the `id` (or a combination of `id` and `V1`).

```
data tmp;
input id $ V1 $ V2;
    datalines;
A Mike 25
A Mike 30
B Mark 4
C Mack 23
C Mack 40
C Mack 90
;
run;

proc sort data=tmp;
by id v1;
run;

proc transpose data=tmp out=trans;
by id V1;
var v2;
run;

proc print;
```

The resulting output looks like this:

```
Obs    id     V1     _NAME_    COL1    COL2    COL3

 1     A     Mike      V2       25      30       .
 2     B     Mark      V2        4       .       .
 3     C     Mack      V2       23      40      90
```

There are a lot of other options available to change the names of the output in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. I did forget to mention that I have a few columns I need to do this for. So can I use multiple var's in proc transpose?

Comment: yes, you can use multiple vars. They will be listed by default under the `_NAME_` variable.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the V2 in the _NAME_ column. Shouldn't that be Mike, Mark, Mack respectively as ID A, B, C? I did try to run this, with 5 variables and SAS EG froze on me... will try on a smaller data set.

Comment: @CGermain You can change the `by` statement to `by id v1;` and it will keep that column

Comment: I'm running this and it's returning the column: _NAME_ with my variable name (in the example all rows would be "V2", another column: _LABEL_ which is also returning "V2" in all of the rows.

Comment: @CGermain Yes, that's a useful feature if you're transposing multiple variables. If you don't want the `_NAME_` and `_LABEL_` variables then just change the `out=` statement to: `out=trans(drop=_NAME_ _LABEL_)`.

Comment: my apologies, I meant _NAME_ and _LABEL_ were populating as the values in every row, versus the variable / column header. The values from the "var"  I use are not writing to additional columns.